# how to get json response with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

array1 = data1

array2 = data2

I have above two arrays, in which I have got the data below (ex-1), and I want it like the array in ex-2, in JSON with codeigniter.

I want to use a foreach loop in codeigniter.

ex-1

```
"data": [
        {
            "singledata": "2",
            "singledata": "1",
            "data1": [
                {
                   "data": "2",
                   "data1": "1",
                   "data2": "0",
                   "data": "9",  
                }]
         },
        ]
```

ex-2

```
"data": [
    {
        "singledata": "2",
        "singledata": "1",
        "data1": [
            {

               "data": "2",
               "data1": "1",
               "data2": "0",
               "data": "9",  
            }
        ]
       "data2"[{

               "data": "2",
               "data1": "1",
               "data2": "0",
               "data": "9",  
       }]     
    },
    ]
```

Comment: Your question quite unclear.

Comment: Are you looking for [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)?

Comment: "I want to" is not a question. What have you tried so far and what problem are you facing? This isn't a free write-my-code service, but we will help you if you can show that you tried to help yourself before asking others to solve it all for you.

Answer (score 0):

Example 1 is a `JSON` string.

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get an array as provided in your Example 2

```
$str = '{"data": [{"singledata": "2","singledata1": "1","data1": [{"data": "2","data1": "1","data2": "0","data3": "9"}]}]}';

$data = json_decode($str);
```

> Note: Your JSON string is invalid